# WPF DockLayoutManager- LayoutGroup dock controls to the left side(when pinning)

Tags: wpf, devexpress, show-hide, docking

I am using DevExpress' DockLayoutManager.
Within the DockLayoutManager, I use LayoutGroup, and within LayoutGroup, I have three LayoutPanels stacked vertically.When I unpin the controls I want all of the panels to dock to the left. By default two of them go top and one goes left. Is there a property in XAML that I must set?

```
 <dxd:DockLayoutManager x:Name="dockLayoutManager"  >

        <dxd:LayoutGroup Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="LayoutRoot">
            <dxd:LayoutGroup Orientation="Vertical">
                <dxd:LayoutPanel ItemWidth="200"
                             Caption="Statuswort"
                             Padding="1">
                    <TextBox BorderThickness="0" />
                </dxd:LayoutPanel>
                <dxd:LayoutPanel ItemWidth="200"
                             Caption="Steuerwort"
                             Padding="1">
                    <TextBox BorderThickness="0" />
                </dxd:LayoutPanel>
                <dxd:LayoutPanel ItemWidth="200"
                             Caption="Übersicht"
                             Padding="1">
                    <TextBox BorderThickness="0" />
                </dxd:LayoutPanel>
            </dxd:LayoutGroup >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [AutoHideGroup.AutoHideType](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfDockingAutoHideGroup_AutoHideTypetopic) attached property:

```
<dxd:DockLayoutManager>
    <dxd:LayoutGroup Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <dxd:LayoutGroup Orientation="Vertical">
            <dxd:LayoutPanel ItemWidth="200" dxd:AutoHideGroup.AutoHideType="Left"
                         Caption="Statuswort"
                         Padding="1">
                <TextBox BorderThickness="0" />
            </dxd:LayoutPanel>
            <dxd:LayoutPanel ItemWidth="200" dxd:AutoHideGroup.AutoHideType="Left"
                         Caption="Steuerwort"
                         Padding="1">
                <TextBox BorderThickness="0" />
            </dxd:LayoutPanel>
            <dxd:LayoutPanel ItemWidth="200" dxd:AutoHideGroup.AutoHideType="Left"
                         Caption="Übersicht"
                         Padding="1">
                <TextBox BorderThickness="0" />
            </dxd:LayoutPanel>
        </dxd:LayoutGroup>
    </dxd:LayoutGroup>
</dxd:DockLayoutManager>
```